# Tricks for a Specific System of Polynomial Equations

Tags: polynomials, roots, groebner-basis

I'm looking for all the complex solutions to the following 3 equations (and for this consider $a$ to be some given constant, so that there are really just 3 unknowns in solving):

$0=2abc+a^2+2ad+b+3d, \ \ \   0 = a d^2 + b^2c + 2ab + 2bd + 3d^2, \ 0 = bd^2 + d^3 + b^2$

I find that all roots have $d = 0$ or $d = 9/2$ or $d = -a^2/(a+1)$.  I also find that one root (at $d = -a^2/(a+1)$) has $cd = 1$ for all a.  The two constant $d=9/2$ and $cd=1$ results are surprising, so was there some way for me to see this from the equations directly in hindsight?  Better yet, is there a general method which shows results like this in foresight for similar equations?  I'm guessing that a mathematician would look at these equations and some change of variables is obvious.

Comment: what are the variables and the constants?

Comment: You can consider all abcd to be variables (I'd really like all solutions in this 4D space, or really 8D space for complex numbers) but, as I wrote, it might be easier to consider a to be some given constant and then think how you would solve for the other 3.

Answer (score 1):

About your second question, a possible general algorithmic method to solve such problems is to compute a Gröbner basis for an elimination ideal.

For instance, by running the following code in the "magma calculator":
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/
we can get automatically the three conditions:

- either $d=0$
- or $d=9/2$
- or $c*d=1$

K:=Rationals();

R$<$a,b,c,d$>$:=PolynomialRing(K,4);

I:=Ideal([2*a * b *c+a^2+2*a*d+b+3*d,     a*d^2+b^2*c+2*a*b+2*b*d+3*d^2,
      b*d^2+d^3+b^2]);

J:=EliminationIdeal(I,{c,d});

f:=GroebnerBasis(J);

Factorization(f[1]);

Comment: Also, if you replace "J:=EliminationIdeal(I,{c,d});" by "J:=EliminationIdeal(I,{a,d});" within this code, you will get automatically d in terms of a.

Comment: Thanks. One odd point is that Magma gives c^2*d^7-9/2*c^2*d^6-2*cd^6+9*cd^5+d^5-9/2*d^4 in its computed GroebnerBasis but Sage does not
(and Magma actually gives 7 basis elements comapared to Sage's 12).  But, Sage does find this element if forced with the command
"I.elimination_ideal([a,b])".  Anyway, my main question still remains:  Could someone look at the original equations and see that simple
factors (2*d-9 and c*d-1) must be present in the Elimination Ideal without the full lengthy basis computation?

Comment: You're welcome. The Groebner basis depends on the monomial ordering you choose : if you want to obtain the eliminant polynomial in the Groebner basis, you require the monomial ordering to be an elimination ordering (see e.g. the Cox/Little/O'Shea book).